# Ajax call freezes UI in internet explorer but works fine in firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, jquery, dwr

I'm making an AJAX call (JSP page in Savvion Business Manager)
and I want to show the LOADING SPINNER while AJAX request is processed

It's working fine in Firefox, but in Internet Explorer the UI freezes until the response is received in callback success function. I'm guessing that Internet Explorer is not making Asynchronous Call. I'm receiving response in Callback success function but the loading spinner freezes when Ajax call is made.

Here is the code

```
function CallbackMyFunction(data)
{
        hideLoadingSpinner();

       // Some Code Here
       ...
}

.
.
.

function AjaxFunction()
{
   showLoadingSpinner();

   SetupAjax.myFunction(jQuery("#Var1").val(), jQuery("#Var2").val(), CallbackMyFunction);

   // Some Code Here
   ...
}
```

DWR is being used for SetupAjax.myFunction()

SetupAjax.myFunction() returns a "AJAXResponseDTO" object which implements "java.io.Serializable"

Comment: Which IE version (menu: About Internet Explorer)?

Comment: what is `setupAjax.myFunction`?

Comment: SetupAjax.myFunction() resturns Ajax Response through DWR framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the `setupAjax.myFunction` is making an async AJAX call. Probably when accessed only from IE. It would be more clear if you post the definition of `setupAjax.myFunction` or the line in which the AJAX call is made exactly.

Comment: I'm working on a tool called "Savvion Business Manager". It creates the response objects for AJAX functions. I'll try to investigate where is the exact call for AJAX in framework

Comment: But why it is freezing on async call ? If its not waiting for response

Comment: An AJAX call can freeze the browser if it is called as `async=true` because the browser has to wait until the request is completed and any response to the request has been obtained

Comment: @Xminds if async=true then why would it wait, ? as it is asyc